# SSIS not writing to partitioned table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I have created a SSIS package for SQL 2016. I have configured the oledb source to read a stored procedure and destination to dump the data to a partition table. I had also implemented logging. It would log which process has started and ended. The logs are in the primary file group. I am storing the partioned data in different filegroups other than primary. The process looks running fine the visual mode in SSIS but cant see any logs written. Now it has stuck at one point and not sure what the problem is . Has anybody faced this issue before

I could see the process running

Partition function

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [financialStatementPartition](datetime) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (N'2013-01-01T00:00:00.000', N'2014-01-01T00:00:00.000', N'2015-01-01T00:00:00.000', N'2016-01-01T00:00:00.000', N'2017-01-01T00:00:00.000')
GO
```

Partion table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FinancialStatementIds](
    [financialCollectionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [companyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dataItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dataItemName] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [dataItemvalue] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [unittypevalue] [int] NULL,
    [fiscalyear] [int] NULL,
    [fiscalquarter] [int] NULL,
    [periodenddate] [datetime] NULL,
    [filingdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [restatementtypename] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [latestforfinancialperiodflag] [bit] NULL,
    [latestfilingforinstanceflag] [bit] NULL,
    [currencyconversionflag] [int] NULL,
    [currencyname] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [periodtypename] [varchar](200) NULL
)
```

Partion Scheme

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [financialStatementRange] AS PARTITION [financialStatementPartition] TO ([PRIMARY], [CT1], [CT2], [CT3], [CT4], [CT5])
GO
```

Comment: Did you check blocked processes? When SSIS waits for something, it's probably your previous (unfinished) or another session which using the objects. Check WhoIsActive tool (you can find link here: http://sqlplayer.net/tools/)

Comment: I ran the WhoIsActive stored proc. It shows the wait_info is (1620ms)ASYNC_NETWORK_IO and status suspended. This is for the query that my SSIS is executing. Not sure why. Has it got to do not able to dump the data into my partition as I can see it has sucessfully read the source

Comment: Any values in [blocking_session_id] column?

Comment: its working now. There was an some infra work happening one the server while my processing was running. Its working now